# Server certificate hash code changes between java versions

Tags: java, ssl, hash, https

I am testing the following code to lookup certificate hash code on my machine and then run the same code on a different vm with java 7.

I am puzzled to see the difference on hash code.

Here's my code:

```
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HttpsURLConnection urlc = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL("https://www.google.com").openConnection();
    print_https_cert(urlc);
}


private static void print_https_cert(HttpsURLConnection con) {

    if (con != null) {

        try {

            System.out.println("Response Code : " + con.getResponseCode());
            System.out.println("Cipher Suite : " + con.getCipherSuite());
            System.out.println("\n");

            Certificate[] certs = con.getServerCertificates();
            for (Certificate cert : certs) {
                System.out.println("Cert Type : " + cert.getType());
                System.out.println("Cert Hash Code : " + cert.hashCode());
                System.out.println("Cert Public Key Algorithm : "
                        + cert.getPublicKey().getAlgorithm());
                System.out.println("Cert Public Key Format : "
                        + cert.getPublicKey().getFormat());
                System.out.println("\n");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
}
```

**Here's what I get with java 1.7.0_79**

> Response Code : 200
>
> Cipher Suite : TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
>
> Cert Type : X.509 Cert Hash Code : 10920939 Cert Public Key Algorithm
>   : RSA Cert Public Key Format : X.509
>
> Cert Type : X.509 Cert Hash Code : 6561088 Cert Public Key Algorithm :
>   RSA Cert Public Key Format : X.509
>
> Cert Type : X.509 Cert Hash Code : 8774863 Cert Public Key Algorithm :
>   RSA Cert Public Key Format : X.509

**and here's the output with java 1.8.0_77**

> Response Code : 200 Cipher Suite :
>   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>
> Cert Type : X.509 Cert Hash Code : -106561125 Cert Public Key
>   Algorithm : RSA Cert Public Key Format : X.509
>
> Cert Type : X.509 Cert Hash Code : 771393018 Cert Public Key Algorithm
>   : RSA Cert Public Key Format : X.509
>
> Cert Type : X.509 Cert Hash Code : 349192256 Cert Public Key Algorithm
>   : RSA Cert Public Key Format : X.509

Should the hash code be same or am I missing something here ?

Comment: Connection is using a different cipher suite with a different hash alogrithm? TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 vs TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hascode() method of  `java.security.cert.Certificate` has changed. At least for openjdk:

java7
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/security/cert/Certificate.java#Certificate.hashCode%28%29

java8
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/security/cert/Certificate.java#Certificate.hashCode%28%29

The hashcode is allowed to change between the jdk version. It primary use is to store `Object`s in `HashMap`s. It's absolutely disregarded to pass the hashcode of an object "outside" or persisting it.

If you need a hashsum of the certificate I recommend you to implement your own hashing function so you are not dependent on internal behaviour which is allowed to change.

There is no strict algorithm how to compute a hashcode for a Java object. Implementors just have to align with the hashcode() and equals() contract.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--

Answer (score 0):

A `hashCode()` isn't the same between different executions of the same program, let alone different Java versions. You're calling the wrong method. You should be calling `X509Certificate.getSerialNumber()`.